# Can't get the inner exception of an exception in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am getting an exception from a call to Entity Framework which says I have to see the inner exception. I added a try/catch statement like so:

```
try {
//call to EF in a library
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
int = 0:  //breakpoint here
}
```

and when I tried to look at ex, this is what I got. Why are all the properties blank like this? It's the same issue in the locals window. Seems like VS can't get the details for the exception or something. I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.3.1.

[image]

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this?

Comment: No. A ticket was filed with Microsoft and they eventually closed it because a repro couldn't be provided for them.